# Google reCaptcha verification popup not displaying properly in Mat Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha, angular-material2

I added google reCaptcha in angular material dialog form. But when reCaptcha opens verification popup, it display above the form like in pic.

[image]

I also found that whenever mat dialog opens it adds the negative margins to the html tag. 
And if I remove the margin the captcha verification popup goes into right place but then mat dialog not display properly. I am confused how to make both popup in right place.

Comment: In Material Design, you should not open a dialog over another dialog. Either reuse the mat-dialog to display the captcha verification, or close the mat-dialog while the captcha dialog is open.

Comment: @G.Tranter I'm experiencing the same issue here as OP. What I'm not clear on from your comment is exactly how you would close a dialog containing the form with the captcha in it while that captcha is open.

Comment: @JohnRix my comments were about Material Design in general. I don't know the recaptcha service at all, but in Angular Material, closing and re-opening dialogs should be simple - https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api. (Don't confuse dialog closure with form submission/cancellation.) You can also use the same dialog - hiding the form content when displaying the verification content (assuming recaptcha lets you do this). An alternative solution is to not use a dialog for the form.

Comment: @G.Tranter Yes, my comment/question was a bit flippant in hindsight! I did solve this yesterday by dynamically rendering and executing the capture after my dialog box was closed. Took a bit of rejigging but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem(kind of hack) at that time only but waiting for proper solution.

Peoples asking why I am adding captcha in popup, so guys its product requirement so can't change.

So what I did, I check for the captcha challenge popup when it appears I change the margins set by the material dialog in html tag like below.

```
checkForChallengePopup() {
    const html: HTMLElement = this.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    this.challengePopup = this.document.querySelector(`[title='recaptcha challenge']`);
    if (this.challengePopup) {
      this.challengePopup.parentElement.style.top = html.style.top.replace('-', '');
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkForChallengePopup();
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
```

And yeah it keep on checking for the challenge pop-up till main dialog is not closed so kind a dirty but did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but anyway that's okay.
You can create some CSS class with `top: 0 !important;` and apply it to  tag when user clicks on ReCaptcha within the material dialog.
And don't forget to remove that class from  after ReCaptcha verification is done or after the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

call `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` right before you launch the login dialog